# How do I create a 2D array in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, hdl, testbench

I want to use a 2D array in a Verilog testbench. I tried it this way:

```
module tb;

    reg [7:0] DataToSend [0:7] = {8'h01, 8'h10, 8'h22, 8'h32, 8'h55, 8'hAA, 8'hAB, 8'h88};

endmodule
```

But this gives me the following error:

`cannot assign a packed type to an unpacked type`

What's the correct way? And is it that it doesn't work in Verilog but would work in SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 4):

The syntax in your code is only supported by **SystemVerilog** (IEEE Std 1800).  It is not supported by **Verilog** (IEEE Std 1364).

In **Verilog** 1364-2005, section 4.9.3 *Memories* (emphasis added):

> An n-bit reg can be assigned a value in a single assignment, **but a
> complete memory cannot**. To assign a value to a memory word, an index
> shall be specified.

Most simulators are capable of understanding **SystemVerilog** (SV) syntax, but many do not have the features *enabled* by default.  You likely need to enable the SV features when you run a simulation.  Refer to your simulator documentation.  This is the simplest way to avoid the syntax error.

Otherwise, if you are stuck with **Verilog** for some reason, then there are ways to avoid the syntax error.  For example:

```
reg [7:0] DataToSend [0:7];
initial begin
    DataToSend[0] = 8'h01;
    DataToSend[1] = 8'h10;
    // etc.
    DataToSend[7] = 8'h88;
end
```